# Different timeframe in a study

Tags: pine-script

I use this indicator

```
study("SSL Hybrid", overlay=true)
show_Baseline = input(title="Show Baseline", type=input.bool, defval=true)
show_SSL1 = input(title="Show SSL1", type=input.bool, defval=false)
show_atr = input(title="Show ATR bands", type=input.bool, defval=true)
//ATR
atrlen = input(14, "ATR Period")
mult = input(1, "ATR Multi", step=0.1)
smoothing = input(title="ATR Smoothing", defval="WMA", options=["RMA", "SMA", "EMA", "WMA"])

ma_function(source, atrlen) => 
    if smoothing == "RMA"
        rma(source, atrlen)
    else
        if smoothing == "SMA"
            sma(source, atrlen)
        else
            if smoothing == "EMA"
                ema(source, atrlen)
            else
                wma(source, atrlen)
atr_slen = ma_function(tr(true), atrlen)
////ATR Up/Low Bands
upper_band = atr_slen * mult + close
lower_band = close - atr_slen * mult

////BASELINE / SSL1 / SSL2 / EXIT MOVING AVERAGE VALUES
maType = input(title="SSL1 / Baseline Type", type=input.string, defval="HMA", options=["SMA","EMA","DEMA","TEMA","LSMA","WMA","MF","VAMA","TMA","HMA", "JMA", "Kijun v2", "EDSMA","McGinley"])
len = input(title="SSL1 / Baseline Length", defval=60)
```

I have add timeframe="D" in the first line study but there is a error.

Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 3: Unknown argument 'timeframe' of type 'literal string'

How can i fix this ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `v4`. In `v4`, it is called `resolution`.

```
study("SSL Hybrid", overlay=true, resolution="", resolution_gaps=true)
```